# How to find Gutenberg block code and call it from template parts

Tags: wordpress-theming, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to include a Gutenberg block - the Search widget - within a template part, so I thought looking at the code within the `post_content` field of the `wp_posts` table might help:

```
<!-- wp:search {"label":"","placeholder":"Search...","width":100,"widthUnit":"%","buttonText":"Search","buttonPosition":"button-inside","buttonUseIcon":true,"className":""} /-->
```

But I don't really know how to find the code or php file this refers to.

How can I use it to add that Gutenberg block into the php code of the template part `site-nav.php`, so the search box is part of the main menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a Gutenberg block to show a search field in your template code. You can use the [`get_search_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) function directly in your PHP. That is the same function used by the search widget in WordPress.

Comment: Ahh thank you. So basically that "comment" line is how Gutenberg encodes its blocks, and the `wp:search` part of the block represents the Search block? (And that standard G'berg block basically just calls `get_search_form()`, with theme styling.)

Comment: @Rickmakeitquick Yup. That's pretty much the "magic" of how Gutenberg works. It uses HTML comments `<!-- wp:search { attributes here } /-->` to define blocks. Most blocks will also include the full HTML output, but some blocks allow for server side rendering (as is the case with the `wp:search` block).